# Convert an AWT canvas to Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

How do I port an AWT Canvas app to a lightweight Swing Component?

Im guessing its quite simple, perhaps extending Component instead of Canvas and then overrinding the correct paint method (perhaps paintComponent).

However, I cant seem to get it to work. It also uses an update method, and I'm not sure what that does.

The code I'm using is [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkuoi.com%2F~kamikaze%2FJava%2Fcode%2FTerminal.java&ei=x9KDUNCsJsTNhAeAyYDYDg&usg=AFQjCNEle1aodskU2seSPOXFhk-6uuw9Iw&sig2=u1HHqcQO6znBddbfYXR_ZQ&cad=rja).

Comment: Could you post some of the code you tried it might help

Comment: There is no one quick easy fix that I know of. Rather than try to port or translate, it may be better to simply start over from a Swing perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Swing components have nearly identical components of AWT,
as swing was built on top of AWT without native peer windowing.

See this link

http://www.tiki-lounge.com/~raf/jfcmanual/jfc.2.html

One of many blogs on the topic over the years.